# Acceder información de un PDF con PHP

Tags: php, pdf, libreria

Requiero acceder a información de un pdf que descargo y lo tengo ya guardado, dentro de ese pdf hay una tabla y requiero obtener esos registros para posteriormente guardarlos en mi base de datos, requiero opiniones de como podría acceder a esa información de mi pdf .
Gracias

Comment: Hola, tu pregunta se basa en opiniones y es algo que claramente esta en contra de las reglas del sitio.

Tu pregunta será reportada y posteriormente cerrada. Para tu funcionalidad te aconsejo separar la tabla en un archivo .csv que es mas fácil de trabajar.

Comment: Hola Diego, bienvenido, tu pregunta se parece a "tengo este ejercicio, háganlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.